# Footer layout slides up with softkeyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I have a footer layout in my base activity and i extend other activities with base activity. the problem is when soft keyboard open footer slides up with it. i tried

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

but it did not help. Any Solution.?

Comment: Try **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible|stateAlwaysHidden"**

Comment: In your manifest:android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"

Answer (score 0):

set android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a `scrollview` try adding  to the xml

```
android:isScrollContainer="false"
```

And try;

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```